# finding the sum of numbers, + and - using recursion (c)

Tags: c, recursion, sum

i need to find the sum of a sequence of **numbers, + and -** while using only recursion (not allowed to use loops).

I can only change the function and nothing more, that includes the pointer in the function (and can't add anything else to it).
I'm also **not allowed** to use any other library but stdio.h.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 100

int calc_sum_string(char *s);

int main() {
    char s[MAX_LENGTH];
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("%d", calc_sum_string(s));
    return 0;
}

int calc_sum_string(char *s) {
int sum = s[MAX_LENGTH];
if (*s == '\0'){
    return sum;
}
if (*s == '+'){
    sum = calc_sum_string(s-1)+ calc_sum_string(s+1);
}
if (*s == '-'){
    sum = calc_sum_string(s+1) - calc_sum_string(s-1);
    return sum;
}
```

input: `7-8+9`
output: `8`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sample input and expected output would help clarify this post.

Comment: At least there is no conversion part of numbers.

Comment: it seems this is going to be wrong ... i think s is the address of the first of string

Comment: i would prefer to call with index instead of checking `'\0'`

Comment: i entered an input and output. i hope now it's clearer..

Comment: @chux I entered an input and output. I can really use your help :)

Comment: If that's an example of your input, where in your program do you think it's processing any of that input as numeric?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
You failed to show what your program already does, and what you've done to debug it.

Comment: `sscanf` is included in `stdio.h`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 100

//Stringification
#define S_(n) #n
#define S(n) S_(n)

int calc_sum_string(char *s);

int main(void){
    char s[MAX_LENGTH+1];

    scanf("%" S(MAX_LENGTH) "s", s);
    printf("%d", calc_sum_string(s));

    return 0;
}

int calc_sum_string(char *s){
//It is assumed that there is no space character in the character string.
//The string is not changed within this function.
    int n, len;

    if (*s == '\0' || 1 != sscanf(s, "%d%n", &n, &len)){
        return 0;
    }
    return n + calc_sum_string(s + len);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i'm not allowed to use what you wrote in the code - "sscanf(s, %d%n, &n, &len)" i must keep it as simple as i can.

Comment: @AmitBarzelay Please understand the concept first.

Comment: Also, It is not difficult to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Your present code has several problems.  The ones you need to address first include:

- You never use any of the digits to create a base value: the 7, 8, and 9 are never interpreted as numbers.  Your only base case returns 0, so that's the only result your code is capable of reaching.
- Your + and - cases have identical code in them: there's no difference in the processing.
- You reference character positions s-1 and s-3 in your recursive calls.  These move you *backwards* into memory that's not part of your string.  You need to move toward the end of the string.

Fix those items.  If you still have problems, please give us a proper posting of your remaining problems, and we'll help you get over the hump.

Comment: thank you, i changed my post so if you can have a look and help me please :)

Comment: "help me please" is not a problem specification.  I gave you three problem points, but you've addressed only one of them.  You still haven't followed the posting guidelines: show what your program does in its present state, and show the results of your debugging attempts.  You've done neither.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all,
this is my final code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 100

int calc_sum_string(char *s);

int main()
{
char s[MAX_LENGTH];
scanf("%s", s);
printf("%d", calc_sum_string(s));
return 0;
}

int calc_sum_string(char *s)
{
if(*s == '\0')
    return 0;
if (*s == '+'){
    return *(s+1) + calc_sum_string(s+2) - '0';
}
else if (*s == '-'){
    return -(*(s + 1) - '0') + calc_sum_string(s+2);
}
else {
    return *s - '0' + calc_sum_string(s+1);
```