# Addition and subtraction using recursion in a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, recursion

I'm trying to write a function `int sum(char *str)` that adds or subtracts one digit numbers (-9 to -9)  given to it in a string (e.g str="1-3+4-5" the function returns -3) using recursion.

I tried dividing the problem into if conditions in which the first is if the operation is `'+'` then add up `sum(str+1)+sum(str-1)`, the second is if it is `'-'` then subtract `sum(str+1)-sum(str-1)`and the third if it's the number itself then it returns it. I added a condition to stop it if the string is of length `<=1` then the sum is the number itself and it returns it. I tried writing the code using the above logic  and I'm having a hard time with it as it isn't working.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you got so far :-)

Comment: [finding the sum of numbers, + and - using recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782844/finding-the-sum-of-numbers-and-using-recursion-c)

Comment: Note about `sum(str+1)-sum(str-1)`: if divide by minus sign and replace as follows `sum(left_expression)-sum(right_expression)`. This is a mistake as it will be interpreted as follows E.g. 1-2-3-4 ==> 1-(2-3-4) ==> 6. divide like (1) and (-2-3-4) then evaluate (1) + (-2-3-4).